# Layout does not adjust for soft keyboard when already focused EditText is reselected

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyboard

As the title say, my problem occurs when I, for example, focused an EditText, canceled it and tried to focus on it again. The first time it gets the focus the screen readjust to make the EditText be above the Keyboard, but when it already have the focus the keyboard simply covers my EditText. Is there anything I can do to make the screen readjust for both situations?

PS.: 
I already have `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in my Manifest file;

The Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    tools:context=".app.Activities.LoginActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:id="@+id/activity_login">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:id="@+id/editTextLogin"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:id="@+id/editTextPassword"/>

        <Button
            android:text="@string/LoginLogar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/buttonEntrar" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:
After I ran lots of tests, I discovered my problem was in the `EditText`'s `android:gravity="center"` WITH `android:inputType=""`. If I take one of this tags out, my keyboard works perfectly. But I still want to make the text be aligned in the center AND have a specific...

Comment: Please Provide Layout File.

Comment: @AsifPatel I've added the layout file.

Comment: Try to add  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden"` in Manifest file.

Comment: @AsifPatel it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use your layout in an application. It worked fine when I tried to focus on different EditText.
It also worked fine when I cancelled and then again focused on the EditText field.

Could you again explain the issue or may be try not to mention `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in the Manifest file.

Because it works fine without it in my application.

Comment: The Problem is in the EditText's android:gravity="center", without this tag it works perfectly. But I'd like to make the text be in the center...

Comment: You don't use `android:gravity="center"` to align text in center, this is for whole editext object. Try using `android:textAlignment="center"` to make text appear in the center. ...... Let me know if it helps you

Comment: Nop. I've just found out that there is a "crash" between `android:textAlignment` and `android:inputType` if I have one of then, I can't have the other one withoug this bug in the keyboard